# Initialize static class implicitly

Tags: c#, static-classes, static-initialization, static-constructor, static-class

is it possible to initialize a static class on app start up "automatically"?
By automatically I mean without the need of referencing a property.

The reason I want to be able to do this for is that I'd like to automatically theme an app on start up.

Here's a short snippet:

```
static class Settings{
    private static Theme _defaultTheme;
    public static Theme DefaultTheme{
        get{
            return _defaultTheme;
        }
        private set{
            _defaultTheme = value;
            ThemeManager.SetTheme(value);
        }
    }
    static Settings(){
        DefaultTheme = Themes.SomeTheme;
    }
}
```

I know I can ( and that's how it is at the moment ) go with original getter/setter and call

```
ThemeManager.SetTheme( Settings.DefaultTheme );
```

in constructor of App ( it's WPF project ) and it'll do the job, however, at least from my point of view ( correct me if I'm mistaken please ) it'd make more sense for the default theme to apply without the need of explicitly stating it.

Comment: `DefaultTheme` will also need to be static, or you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yeah, missed that in the snippet, sorry.

Comment: You appear to be calling the `DefaultTheme` property recursively and you need a closing bracket for the property.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Thanks, it should be ok now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to initialize a static class on app start up "automatically"? By automatically I mean without the need of referencing a property.

The only way to guarantee that the static constructor will execute is to use the type in some form.  It does not necessary need to be referencing a property (it could be constructing an instance, using a method, etc), but you do need to use the type.  It is possible for the static constructor to never run otherwise.

Your current option, or a variation of it, seems like the best solution.  You could change this to having a single call such as:

```
Settings.InstallDefaultTheme();
```

If you prefer, since the reference of `Settings` would force the static constructor to execute.